# broken photos in iCloud Photos - can I delete everything?

Tags: icloud, photos

I've messed up something in iCloud Photos. I have placeholders for photos going back through time to my very first digital photos (2002!), but they are only placeholders. When I click on the photos, iCloud Photos crashes. I can't select them, I can't do anything.

[image]

[image]

All of these photos are backed up, and I would really like to delete everything on iCloud photos and start over. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Does the **Photos** app crash too?